# Slope and Intercept functions return #Value! (rerror 2015)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a Excel VBA program which displays scatter plots for a series of x,y values and a trend line with the linear least squares equation and R-squared. I would like to capture the Slope and Intercept in my VBA program.  In native XL I would enter something like this in a cell for the slope:

```
=SLOPE(B2:B1026,A2:A1026)
```

However, as shown below, when  I try to do this in VBA I get the  #Value! 2015 error. What am I doing wrong?

I could do some string manipulation to extract them from the Trend Line legend, but I would prefer to do it directly.

I've also tried to use "Application.WorksheetFunction.Intercept..." but that throws an error "unable to get the Intercept property of the worksheetFunction class".

Some example data, graph and slope calculations are shown in jpg image[image: example data, graph and slope calculations]

Here is the related VBA code, note Max is 1026, but I've also coded 1026 directly without any effect.

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).Select
Selection.DisplayEquation = True
Selection.DisplayRSquared = True
Cells(2, 10) = Application.Intercept("$b2:$b" & Max, "$a2:$a" & Max)
Cells(3, 10) = Application.Slope("$b2:$b" & Max, "$a2:$a" & Max)
Cells(4, 10) = Application.RSq("$b2:$b" & Max, "$a2:$a" & Max)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax is wrong

```
Application.Slope("$b2:$b" & Max, "$a2:$a" & Max)
```

According to [WorksheetFunction.Slope method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.slope) the arguments you submit to `Slope` need to be `Range` objects.

```
Application.Slope(Range("$b2:$b" & Max), Range("$a2:$a" & Max))
```